# Control events inside interaction pop up not working

Tags: popup, command, prism, interaction

I have an interaction request pop up and inside that pop up, I have few controls like time picker, radcombobox and so on. I want change events of these controls hit in my view model class using prism commands.

my sample code is not working, time picket value change is not hitting on OnReasonTimeChanged Method.

**XAML file**

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger SourceName=" "  EventName="ValueChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ReasonTimeChanged}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding SummaryConfirmationInteractionRequest}">
            <prism:PopupChildWindowAction>
                <prism:PopupChildWindowAction.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="Auto"
                                    MaxHeight="400" >
                            <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="1"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="820" Height="Auto" MaxHeight="200">
                                <StackPanel Height="Auto" >
                                    <controls:XRadGridView x:Name="UnitsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Units, Mode=OneWay}"
                               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                                  
                               MaxHeight="300"                              
                               IsReadOnly="True"
                               RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                               CanUserInsertRows="False"
                               CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                               ShowColumnHeaders="False"
                               ShowGroupPanel="False"
                               CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                               CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                               AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                        <controls:XRadGridView.Columns>
                                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="DUID"
                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayDuid}"
                                            IsReadOnly="True"
                                            Width="Auto" />
                                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="ReasonTime">
                                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>

                                                        <toolkit:TimePicker  x:Name="ReasonTime"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="20"
                                                MaxWidth="20"
                                                Loaded="ReasonTime_Loaded"
                                                Format="HHmm"

                                                Value="{Binding OfferHeader.ReasonTime, Mode=TwoWay}"                                              
                                                controls:TimePickerExtensions.UpdateBindingOnValueChanged="{Binding ApplyReasonToAll}"
                                                TabIndex="0"/>


                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
 </controls:XRadGridView.Columns>
                                    </controls:XRadGridView>
```

ViewModel code

Inside constructor I have below code

```
 _reasonTimeChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnReasonTimeChanged);
```

command  details

```
private readonly DelegateCommand _reasonTimeChangedCommand;

public ICommand ReasonTimeChanged => _reasonTimeChangedCommand;

public void OnReasonTimeChanged()
{
}
```

Comment: CommandAction should be inside the pop-up, also need some more info like the view model by which I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The `InvokeCommandAction` should be *inside* the popup, to be used within the popup... **but** you bind to the value to a property (`ReasonTime`), and that property should be responsible for notifying the change. *That*'s the view model's job, not just being a container for commands or forwarding properties from some DTO.

Comment: I can't/won't/don't want to (unpaid at least) do your work for you. Also, you didn't even post the view model's code. My advice is to put whatever code you wanted to be in `OnReasonTimeChanged` in the setter of `ReasonTime`, as a starting point. You can refactor it into a service later on, of course.

Comment: I tried this, but it is not hitting to setter, I hope we need to set relative source in the control binding section. Can you please tell me how to set the relative source for a control in rad grid which is inside interaction popup